# How I can check 'undefined' variable in AJAX queries?

Tags: javascript, ajax, undefined

What is the most appropriate way to test if a variable is undefined in JavaScript?

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        if (form != null || form != undefined){
            data = $(form).serialize();
        }
        var json =  JSON.parse(data),
            list = $(table).html(),
            compileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(list),
            result = compileTemplate(json),
            content = doc.getElementById(element);
        content.innerHTML = result;
    },
    dataType: "text"
});
```

I'm looking for a more beautiful way for this check.

Comment: `if( form )` should check if the variable exists and is defined (but I'm sure there are a bunch of edge cases where this may break)

Comment: To test if a variable is  undefined: `if(typeof form === "undefined")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if it is undefined before checking the value so it does not throw an error. Also it needs an AND (&&) not an OR (||).

The official way to do that is to check type.

Change the 'if' statement to say this:

```
if (typeof(form) !== "undefined" && form != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply test `form != null` which will be true if `form` is neither `null` ***or*** `undefined`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        if (form != null){
            data = $(form).serialize();
        }
        var json =  JSON.parse(data),
            list = $(table).html(),
            compileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(list),
            result = compileTemplate(json),
            content = doc.getElementById(element);
        content.innerHTML = result;
    },
    dataType: "text"
});
```

Comment: In this situation, I can not use this method without variable 'form'.

Comment: @cxFaust not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: If I could use this code, I would check the variable before the method. But I use this code with a variable "form" and without.

Comment: The test `if (form != null){` will parse the serialised form data if it's not null or undefined. Is that not what you want?